# Matching elements in array documents sometimes gets very slow

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with about 100.000 documents.
Each document has an array with about ~ 100 elements. Is an array of strings like this:

```
features: [
    "0_Toyota",
    "29776_Grey",
    "101037_Hybrid",
    "240473_Iron Gray",
    "46290_Aluminium,Magnesium",
    "2787_14",
    "9350_1920 x 1080",
    "36303_Y",
    "310870_N",
    "57721_Y"
    ...
```

Making queries like this, are very fast. But sometimes gets very slow, including an specific extra condition inside $and. I have no idea why this happens. When gets slow, it takes more than 40 seconds. Always happens with the same extra condition. It is very possible that it happens with other conditions.

```
db.products.find({ 

    $and:[
    {
        "features" : {
            "$eq" : "36303_N"
        }
    },
    {
        "features" : {
            "$eq" : "91135_IPS"
        }
    },
    {
        "features" : {
            "$eq" : "9350_1366 x 768"
        }
    },
    {
        "features" : {
            "$eq" : "178874_Y"
        }
    },
    {
        "features" : {
            "$eq" : "43547_Y"
        }
    }
    ...
```

I'm running the same mongodb in my unix laptop and on a linux server instance.
Also trying indexing the field "features" with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

use  `$all`  in your mongo query  with your data helps  you to  query for  an array

first  create  index on `features`

use this query  may helps  to you

```
db.products.find( { features: { $all: ["36303_N", "91135_IPS","others..."] } } )
```

by  the  way  , 
if  your  query  is very slow  ,get the slow operation from your mongod log
show your mongodb version .
any  writing  when  query  (write  will  blocking  read  in some version)

Comment: Didn't work with $all. Takes the same time than before. My mongodb version is 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that order inside $all matters. I change the order of elements by its number of documents that exists inside the collection, ascending. Making the query more selective.

Before, the query takes ~ 40 seconds to execute, now, with elements ordered, it takes ~ 22 seconds.

Still many seconds anyway.